# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord' after deploying to Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py

I am getting the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord` when deploying to Heroku and examining the logs after my discord bot fails to come online.

I have the following requirements.txt:

```
dnspython==1.16.0
discord.py==1.6.0
google-api-python-client==2.0.2
pymongo==3.11.3
requests==2.24.0
```

I have tried changing/removing the package number, changing the python version, and looked elsewhere but other solutions do not seem to be working.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Have you added a Python buildpack?

Comment: did you check what else you have in log? Maybe there is other information if it installed correctly modules.